# Position of and length in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have  text like this:

> This is a sample {text}. I want to inform my {Dada} that I have some
>   data which is {not useful}. So I need data to start by { and ends with
>   }. This data needs to {find out}.

Total text have some substrings separated within curly braces `{}`. How can I find the starting position and length of the substring starting with `{` and ending with `}`? Further, I will replace the substring with the processed string.

Comment: Do some research on regular expression, make an attempt, then post your code if you're not getting the results you're expecting.

Comment: What have you tried? We want to see what you have tried and will help correct from there

Comment: *Further I will replace the sub string with processed string.* If you do it in two steps (first find all, then replace all), then you'll make it quite complex: each replace will shift all the found indexes.

Comment: @Shar1er80 and @blackmind Yes i have tried and already implemented an alternative by searching `{` and `}`. Although it works I want Regex version.

Regex rx = new Regex(@"^{[\w\s]+}\b");
            //foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in rx.Matches(text))
            //{
            //    int i = match.Index;

            //}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx), you can check the index of each match by accessing the [`Index`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index(v=vs.110).aspx) property, and the length of each match by checking the [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

If you want to count the curly braces in, you can use `\{(.*?)\}` regex, like this:

```
 var txt = "This is a sample {text}. I want to inform my {Dada} that I have some  data which is {not useful}. So I need data to start by { and ends with }. This data needs to {find out}.";
 var rgx1 = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}");
 var matchees = rgx1.Matches(txt);
 // Get the 1st capure groups
 var all_matches = matchees.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
 // Get the indexes of the matches
 var idxs = matchees.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Index).ToList();
 // Get the lengths of the matches
 var lens = matchees.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Length).ToList();
```

Outputs:

[image] [image] [image]

Perhaps, you will want to use a dictionary with search and replace terms, and that will be more effecient:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("old", "new");
var ttxt = "My {old} car";
// And then use the keys to replace with the values
var output = rgx1.Replace(ttxt, match => dic[match.Groups[1].Value]);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will not have nested curly braces, you can use the following:

```
var input = @"This is a sample {text}. I want to inform my {Dada} that I have some data which is {not useful}. So I need data to start by { and ends with }. This data needs to {find out}."
var pattern = @"{[^]*}"
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) {
    string subString = match.Groups(1).Value;
    int start = match.Groups(1).Index;
    int length = match.Groups(1).Length;
}
```